# cambiar foto perfil Firebase Auth Android

Tags: android, firebase

¿Se puede cambiar directamente la foto aprentando a un botón, o es mejor sacar otro fragment? Después de la elección de la foto no tengo ni idea de como continuar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
public void changephoto(View view){
    final int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 71;

    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);



    FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

    UserProfileChangeRequest profileUpdates = new UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder()
            .setPhotoUri(Uri.parse(""))//Falta la eleccion de la foto
            .build();

    user.updateProfile(profileUpdates)
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                    }
                }
            });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Debes modificar el perfil del usuario para añadir la URL de la imagen,
en la documentación de firebase lo puedes encontrar todo muy detallado, aqui un ejemplo:

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

UserProfileChangeRequest profileUpdates = new UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder()
        .setPhotoUri(Uri.parse("URL_DE_LA_IMAGEN_QUE_QUIERAS_PONER"))
        .build();

user.updateProfile(profileUpdates)
        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "User profile updated.");
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Eso no responde en nada a la pregunta, si lees un poco veras que el código que has puesto ya lo tengo yo

Comment: Vale, perdón, no había visto el código, la verdad es que no entiendo muy bien la pregunta. ¿Te refieres a que dónde abrir la cámara, si en un fragment o en la misma ventana? Puedes acceder a la cámara con un intent o a la biblioteca de imágenes también y en la respuesta te devolvería la fotografía a subir. Espero que sea eso lo que buscas, un saludo

Comment: la cuestion que cuando le doy al boton se habre la galeria para elegir la foto, lo que no se es seguir para que la foto que elijo se ponga en 
.setPhotoUri(Uri.parse("")); 
y cambie asi la foto de perfil

Comment: No te puedo pegar código por falta de tiempo, pero lo que debes hacer es el dato que recibas en OnActivityResult convertirlo a Bitmap y subirlo a Firebase Storage y desde ahí coger la url para ponerlo en el usuario. Si luego tengo unos minutos intento hacerte el código y enviartelo, pero es bastante simple. Espero que te sea de ayuda

Comment: Se agradece, yo lo tengo hecho pero en una activity normal, en el fragment y con la vista no llego a hacerlo

Comment: Puedes probar a hacer toda la parte del modelo desde el activity, así te resultará mas sencillo, lo que yo solía hacer es enviar el "view" del onviewcreated a el activity y desde ahí tratarlo, prueba así, igual te resulta mas sencillo

Answer (score 0):

Mira hace poco me paso algo similar a ti, busque y busque mucho por ahi, y la cuestion es que habian muchos metodos, y la mayoria a mi no me funcionaba. Hasta que tuve suerte y encontre una que si me funcionaba. Te la pongo la pruebas y ya me dices. En la solucion que te pongo puedes usar como quieras una vez tienes la url que quieres coger. En este ejemplo cogo la imagen de galeria o camara y la pongo en un ImageView. Es aqui donde la uri que se consigue supongo que sera lo que te hacia falta para tu solucion.

```
private void openGallery(){
    Intent gallery=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(gallery, PICK_IMAGE);
}

private void openCamera(){
    File fotoFile=new File(context.getFilesDir(),"fotoPerfil");
    String pathFotoFile=fotoFile.getAbsolutePath();
    Uri fotoUri=Uri.fromFile(fotoFile);
    Intent camera=new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if(camera.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null){
        camera.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fotoUri);
        startActivityForResult(camera, RESP_TOMAR_FOTO);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(resultCode==RESULT_OK && (requestCode==PICK_IMAGE || requestCode==RESP_TOMAR_FOTO )){
        imageUri=data.getData();
        imgPerfil_newuser_class.setImageURI(imageUri);
        imgPerfil_toolbar_class.setImageURI(imageUri);


    }
}
```

Yo aqui cree una variable estatica para poder cambiar las imagenes en los layouts.

Comment: Como veras (imgPerfil_newuser_class y imgPerfil_toolbar_class) son las variables estaticas que apuntan a los ImageView de los layouts. Asi cuando se selecciona la imagen de la galeria o se hace la foto desde la camara, automaticamente me cambia las imagenes en los layouts. A ti supongo que el unico dato que necesitas es el de la variable "imageUri=data.getData()"