# Subir foto de la cámara al Storage Android Studio

Tags: java, android, firebase, database-android

Soy nuevo en Android Studio, y no sé muy bien cómo subir una foto de la cámara al storage. El programa debe subir una fotografía con nombre "fecha" en una carpeta con el nombre solicitado en la anterior actividad (variable "dato"). Este es mi código:

variables:

```
   private Button btnCamera, btnGallery, btnList;
   private StorageReference storage;                                                               //referencia para usar Storage
   private static final int GALLERY_INTENT = 1;
   private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE = 2;
   private static final String AUTHORITY=BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID+".provider";
   private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
   private File file = null;

   Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
   SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
   String fecha = df.format(c.getTime());
```

método onCreate:

```
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_select_method);

       storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();


       btnCamera = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonCamera);
       btnGallery = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonGallery);
       btnList = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonList);


       String dato = getIntent().getStringExtra("dato");
       TextSalida.setText(dato);

       //-------------METODO TOMAR FOTO CON LA CAMARA-------------
       btnCamera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View view) {
               /*Intent btnImage = new Intent(SelectMethod.this, TakePhoto.class);
               startActivity(btnImage);*/
               Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
               if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                   startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE);
               }
           }
       });

   }
```

metodo onActivityResult de la cámara:

```
   @Override
   protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
       super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
               if(requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                   Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                   StorageReference filepath = storage.child(getIntent().getStringExtra("dato"));
                   //File image = new File(fecha + ".jpg");
                   Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(fecha + ".jpg"));
                   filepath.putFile(uri)
                           .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                               @Override
                               public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                                   Toast.makeText(SelectMethod.this, "La imagen se subió correctamente.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                               }
                           })
                           .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                               @Override
                               public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                                   Toast.makeText(SelectMethod.this, "La subida falló.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                               }
                           });
               }
       }
   }
```

El caso es que no se crear bien la imagen cuando se realiza la fotografía, para luego subirla con un nombre específico al storage mediante Uri.

Answer (score 0):

Mira, aqui puse un ejemplo de como tratar las imagenes desde la Camara y la Galeria.

[cambiar foto perfil Firebase Auth Android](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/166077/cambiar-foto-perfil-firebase-auth-android/358563#358563)

Aqui te pongo, como subo las imagenes al FirebaseStorage.

```
private void openGallery(){
    Intent gallery=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(gallery, PICK_IMAGE);
    Log.d("NewUser","PICK_IMAGE="+PICK_IMAGE);
}


private void openCamera(){
File fotoFile=new File(context.getFilesDir(),"fotoPerfil");
String pathFotoFile=fotoFile.getAbsolutePath();
Uri fotoUri=Uri.fromFile(fotoFile);
Intent camera=new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
if(camera.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null){
    camera.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fotoUri);
    startActivityForResult(camera, RESP_TOMAR_FOTO);
}
 

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Log.d("NewUser","onActivityRestult START!");
    if(resultCode==RESULT_OK && (requestCode==PICK_IMAGE || requestCode==RESP_TOMAR_FOTO )){
        imageUri=data.getData();
        imgPerfil_newuser_class.setImageURI(imageUri);
    }
}
```

Desde aqui llamo el metodo para el upload!, con los datos obtenidos anteriormente. El imageUri es el resultado del onActivityResult(), y el nom es una variable añadida.

```
Manager.uploadImg(this,imageUri, "images/users/imgPerfil_"+nom);
```

Y aqui, la subida al FirebaseStorage:

```
// ****************************************************************************
// *   Metode per a pujar la image del usuari al Firebase Storage             *
// ****************************************************************************
public void uploadImg(final Context context, final Uri uri, String ruta){
    Log.d("FileManager","Start uploadImg()");
    StorageReference riversRef=storageRef.child(ruta);
    riversRef.putFile(uri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
            Uri downloadUrl=taskSnapshot.getUploadSessionUri();
            Log.d("FileManager","uploadImg OK!");
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            Log.e("FileManager","Error en uploadImg ==>"+e);
        }
    });
```

A mi me funciona bastante bien, si quieres puedes probar a ver en que te falla, pero por lo visto el error debe estar el la variable filepath que creaste o los permisos de Firebase.

Comment: Un negativo por la respuesta????, si lo se ni me molesto en contestar!!!!! Este metodo me costó mucho encontrarlos hace mucho y al final resultó ser de los mejores que encontré. Vaya animos que me dais... como para seguir ayudando....

Comment: no te frustres. La mayoría indicamos qué es lo que no funciona de la respuesta. Todavía hay que esperar a que el OP la revise y comente si le sirvió o no. PD. Yo no te voté :)

Comment: @Alejandro gracias, he estado probando lo que me has mandado pero no me funciona. ¿Cómo inicializas el context del metodo openCamera? Mi error creo que está a la hora de crear el archivo en el que guarde la foto, porque la subida del archivo que tengo para una imagen de la galería es como la que me enseñas tú, pero cuando intentaba subir la imagen me decía que el Intent era null.

Comment: @PedroAGalera modifica el método private void openCamera(Context context){ ... y lo llamas de esta forma openCamera(getApplicationContext()); ,

Comment: El context lo tengo global anteriormente llamandolo desde el principal Context context=this; pero como dice @PedroAGalera tambien puedes hacerlo. En tus prueba a mi me falló el nombre de archivo al indroducirle la variable fecha, ya que contenia espacios. Intenta ponerle otro nombre o trasforma la fecha en entero largo, y luego introducelo como string.